# How Can we apply action like FULL OUTER JOIN on selected tables?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, full-outer-join

I am collecting data for graph from two different tables. I have previously applied left join but i am getting graph for only bookings.

I wanted it for booking ang visits both.
tables are
Bookings Table

```
    bookid | uid | dateTime
    --------------------------
    1      | 2   | 2017-01-20 12:55
```

and visits table

```
visitid | dateTime         | ip_Address
-----------------------------------------
1       | 2017-01-20 12:55 | 192.168.1.2
```

my sql query is below

```
Select a.date,ifnull(a.bookings,0) AS bookings,ifnull(b.visits,0) as visits
from
(
(SELECT DATE( date ) as date , COUNT( booking_id ) AS bookings FROM  `booking` GROUP BY DATE( date )) As a 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT DATE(date) as date,COUNT( ip_address ) as visits FROM visit_counter group by DATE(date)) As b
on a.date = b.date 
)
WHERE a.date BETWEEN (NOW( ) - INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND NOW( )  
ORDER BY a.date ASC
```

Here Full Outer Join is raising syntax error.
Previously i have applied Left Join and It was working.

Comment: mysql doesn't allow full outer join

Comment: then what is in replacement

Comment: check this ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql